# Python openpyxl Font TypeError

Tags: python, openpyxl

So in my program i was using last version(3.1.2) of openpyxl module:

```
from openpyxl.styles.fonts import Font
```

and setting font of cells like this:

```
main.cell(row=row, column=col).font = Font(color='00808080')
```

However, from today it stopped working. It gives an error:

```
TypeError: Font.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

If i go to Font class i can clearly see that it is not unexpected.

It was working perfectly fine before today.

I checked, nothing changed, versions stayed the same, code stayed the same.

I even tried to reinstall openpyxl package, and install a few earlier versions, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was simultaniously importing

```
from openpyxl.styles.fonts import Font
```

and

```
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Font
```

So i added to first one import Font as ... and it started working

Comment: This isn't answer. You should update the question to show the mistake you made.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the error is caused by an update to the openpyxl module or a related dependency. One thing you can try is to explicitly import the Font class from the `openpyxl.styles` package instead of from `openpyxl.styles.fonts`, like this:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font
main.cell(row=row, column=col).font = Font(color='00808080')
```

If that doesn't work, you could also try specifying the color using a different format, such as an RGB tuple or hex code, like this:

```
main.cell(row=row, column=col).font = Font(color='FF808080')
```

Alternatively, you could try using a different font attribute to achieve the desired effect, such as setting the font name or size.

Answer (score -1):

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font
```